# Trying to target a specific .NET version in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change the target version to .NET 3.5.

The project I'm using was created by Unity, the game engine.  I'm doing this so I can install nuget dependencies

But when I try to open the properties menu, either the screen flashes white and nothing happens, or a window appears which looks significantly different than the one pictured in the instructions.  This is the properties menu I'm seeing:

[properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmjCq.jpg)

This is what I'm clicking on to get the properties not found dialogue:

[where I'm clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKOm8.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: You're opening Properties on a file. Right click the project itself and choose properties.

Comment: Well, you are looking at the file properties. Right Click on the Project name under Solution explorer.

Comment: When I do that, the screen flashes a bit and nothing happens

Comment: Try to set the .NET version manually in the app.config or web.config : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx ... Literally how to do this in vs2015

Comment: Thanks Adam, I tried that but had to take the link out because I'm limited to two.  If it had worked I would obviously not be asking here

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Unity 5.3.5, and vstu 2.3  Found this thread today which I think explains what's going on http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/visual-studio-tools-for-unity-2-2.384014/

Answer (score 4):

You aren't changing the project properties, you are looking at one individual class properties page.

You need to right click on the Project, and select properties as demonstrated below. [image]

That will open up this page.

[image]

Comment: Edited the image to show what happens when I click on the project

Comment: What are you clicking on to get that window to appear?

Comment: That looks like what happens when you right click the `solution` and do properties @Sawyer

Comment: Edited to show what I'm clicking on, it's not the solution.  I do get a properties window when I click on the solution, but it's not the one folks are pointing me to

Comment: I see...Your "project" is not a usual c# project. What project type did you choose when creating it? Whatever type you chose is not the type that I or Microsoft's document that you linked is referencing.

Comment: The project was created within Unity, the game engine.  I'll add that to the question too

Comment: I see. I have no experience with Unity, and the article you linked is for normal .net project templates, not Unity.

Comment: Thanks - I found this article, that suggests it *should* work.  Maybe a unity person will come out of the woodwork
 http://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/unity-and-nuget/

Answer (score 0):

Right Click your project and click properties or in visual studio **Project->ProjectName Properties...** at the bottom. Then on the **Application** tag or tab, there will be Target Framework: Change this to `.NET Framework 3.5`.

Comment: Edited the image to show what happens when I click on the project